# Get woocommerce product price by id

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i make one shortcode for get product title, image and price. i am getting all title, link and image properly but not getting price. but problem is

```
add_shortcode('product_data','custom_product_function');
function custom_product_function($atts)
{
    $post_id = $atts['id'];
    $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    $link = get_the_permalink($post_id);
    $price = get_the_price($post_id);
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'thumbnail');
    $data ='<div class="releated-products wow fadeInUp"><a href="'.$link.'">'.$image.'<h5>'.$title.'</h5><h6>'.$price.'</h6></a></div>';
    return $data;
}
```

`$price = get_the_price($post_id);` i guess this function not correct

any idea how to get price now.

Thanks you

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can create a product object using the following function:

`$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );`

And after that you will be able to access to all product's data. All available methods can be found [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html), but the ones you need are:

```
$product->get_regular_price();
$product->get_sale_price();
$product->get_price();
```

Comment: thanks for reply. i look that already. checking again. but for that i need to change my shortcode function different way. am i right ? is there anyway to do inside my shortcode

Comment: Just add `$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );` somewhere above $price and set `$price = $product->get_price()`.

Comment: This crashed my local

Comment: WC_Product class and methods link correction:

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html